Kotlin Multi Platform with Koin
I'm developing a payment SDK and I want to use Koin for dependency injection. However, I'm encountering some issues during deployment.
The way I designed the SDK involves initializing a Koin Manager object with methods to detect whether the client application has included the Koin library. If Koin is there, the SDK is supposed to intercept their implementation as if not, it should do nothing and proceed with the SDK's internal process. But I've found that this approach isn't working as expected.

The app crashes instantly if the application doesn't include or implement the Koin library even though I have the method to use the Koin library in my KMP.

How can I ensure that my SDK can handle Koin initialization internally without depending on whether the client application includes the Koin library or not, and still working either way?
I tried to shade Koin dependency with Shadow, I tried to add the dependency in the source set of my SDK, but the issues is still exists as the vendor's app will crashed if they did not include the Koin library.

tasks.withType<com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowJar> {
    archiveClassifier.set("shadow")
    relocate("io.insert-koin", "com.kointest.shadowed.io.insert-koin")
}


 sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("io.insert-koin:koin-core:3.3.0")
            }
        }
        val androidMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("io.insert-koin:koin-android:3.3.0")
            }
        }
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test"))
            }
        }
    }

